# Source code of a confluence macro

Tags: macros, confluence

Confluence version: 5.5.2.

I need to know how I can see the actual source code of a macro in Confluence. I tried adding macros, then right-clicking the page to view the source code, but that doesn't really help.

What I am trying to do:

With the existing macro, task list (the checkboxs), I need to modify the code in a way such that changing the value from true to false (pretty sure it is the onClick() function) or vice versa will send an e-mail to all "Watchers" of that page.

Would this even be possible? The changes I make need to be recognized on the server so that the changes don't only take place on my computer. Also, I don't even know if I can view the actual source without downloading an external plug-in (which won't work for certain reasons). Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around. If you go into settings (under profile pic), then go to e-mail and select all the checkboxes provided, it will solve my problem. Any small cahnge made in the document will be e-mailed to all watchers.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for Confluence macros can be found either in the User Macro section of the Administration panel for inhouse macros or in the plugin code. The first port of call is bitbucket.org for Atlassian plugin code.

To view the code for Atlassian plugins you will need to access the source from Atlassian. E.g. [Tasklist Plugin in BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/confluence-tasklist-plugin).

You can also download the jar installer for this plugin from the [Atlassian Marketplace Dynamic Tasklist 2](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/confluence.extra.dynamictasklist2/versions) page, change the extension from .jar to .zip and then unzip the plugin to view the plugin contents.